# XML String parsing in Android?

Tags: android

I use the following code to parse the XML file.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory;
DocumentBuilder builder;
InputStream is;
Document dom;
try {
    factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    is = new FileInputStream(strFileName);
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    dom = builder.parse(is);
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

Instead of XML file is there any way to parse the String.

```
String xml="<?xml version="1.0"?> <name> Application</name> <demo> Demo </demo> </xml>";
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is very unclear. If you already have a string - why would you even need a XML parser?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can convert your string to an InputStream using [ByteArrayInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html):

```
String xml ="valid xml here";
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));

dom = builder.parse(is);
```

Comment: i get this problem while using your code java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.w3c.dom.Document javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 3):

You can use [StringReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) :

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
InputSource is = new InputSource(sr);
Document d = builder.parse(is);
```

Comment: Should the second line be `InputSource is = new InputSource(sr);` instead?

Comment: i get this problem while using your code java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.w3c.dom.Document javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource)' on a null object reference